# Looping over response to save items to the DB (Django,Scrapy)

Tags: python, django, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm on a project where i crawl the web for various furnitures and get their attributes. I used DjangoItem to save these data to my DB. My problem is getting the response count to use it in a for loop. I don't know if it's the best way to do it(probably not). Here's my spider:

```
    def parse(self, response):
    now = timezone.now()
    for item in response.css('.page-content-area'):

        for i in range(5):
            furnitureItem = FurnitureItem()
            furnitureItem['furniture_type'] = 'Chair'
            furnitureItem['name'] = item.css('h2 a::text').extract()[i]
            furnitureItem['description'] = item.css('a span::text').extract()[i]
            furnitureItem['href'] = item.css('h2 a::attr(href)').extract()[i]
            furnitureItem['img_source'] = item.css('.lazy::attr(data-original)').extract()[i]
            furnitureItem['price'] = item.css('.mt3::text').extract()[i]
            furnitureItem['last_update'] = now
            yield furnitureItem
```

Each key here has multiple values. I looped 5 times to see if it saves 5 items to the DB. It does. What i want is to get response's count to use it in this loop. I just started to use Scrapy and i feel like i can't use it effectively.
I'll appreciate any advice.
And an extra question: What does a pipeline do and in which cases should i use it. I've read official documents but i feel like i need a simple explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: "What i want is to get response's count to use it in this loop". Could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: When i run the spider without the loop, it saves one item to the DB with a list of values for it's each attribute, i.e. name = [chair1,chair2,..]. I want to save those chairs one by one to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the use case, i.e. why you actually need the response count. Depending on how to want to implement the storing logic, you either have the items in some iterable (which you can iterate and don't need the count beforehand), or you use the item pipeline storing items one by one as they go though the pipeline.

Item pipelines are used to process items as they are returned from the Scrapy engine. You can mangle the items, perform actions based on the items' values or discard them. I think the [examples](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#item-pipeline-example) in the documentation are quite illustrative. Also, you might look at [Scrapy architecture](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html) to see the big picture and where pipelines fit in.